# Proper way to do pagination of 50.000+ rows in Datastore (golang)?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore, google-compute-engine

I'm in the situation where my queries return a lot (potentially over 50.000+) results, but for each page I only want to display 50 results and then make it possible to click a next/previous button..

I was thinking this could be achieved this way:

```
querySize := 50
total, err := db.client.Count(ctx, query) 
numPages := (total % querySize)
if numPages > curPage {
    return nil, errors.New("out of range")
}
offset := querySize * curPage
query = query.Offset(offset).Limit(querySize)
var app []AppStoreApp
if _, err := db.client.GetAll(ctx, query, &app); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
return &app, nil
```

But is this efficient, and is there a better way to do it?

Also, it's simple to check whether a previous button should be enabled since you can just say `if curPage > 1` then it should be enabled.. but how about checking if next button should be enabled? Perhaps by setting querySize to 51, and then only using 50 of the results?

Any help/advice would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You should be looking at Query Cursors: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/query-cursors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pagination with batch queries? Is it possible to batch gets from the datastore and get a cursor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902903/pagination-with-batch-queries-is-it-possible-to-batch-gets-from-the-datastore-a)

Comment: Using Query Cursors [like this (example20)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/docs/appengine/datastore/queries/queries.go)?, and then just break the for loop after 50 iterations?

Comment: it *looks* like it, indeed, but I'm not 100% certain - I'm a python user.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot :)